# How to write the properties for variables in c while converting from objective c

Tags: c++, objective-c, visual-c++, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I am porting a project called sneakyness / SneakyInput hosted on github at https://github.com/sneakyness/SneakyInput. It's in objective-c for cocos2d-iphone . I want to port that to c++ for use in cocos2d-x.
In SneakyJoystick.h
The properties like 
`@property (nonatomic, readonly) CGPoint stickPosition;` where 
`CGPoint stickPosition` is a variable which is already defined. I have defined this variable normally as `CCPoint stickPosition;` But I am very confused about the 
`@property (nonatomic, readonly) CGPoint stickPosition;` 
whether I should write it in c++ code or leave it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have code in C++ you can leave it as it is(C++) and interact with it with Objective-C without problems.

If instead your intentions are to rewrite everything to Objective-C then the objective C property should be put in place of a property in C++ :

### Property in C++

```
private: 
    int x; 
public:  
    int getX()
    {
        return x;
    }
    void setX(int value) 
    {
        x = value;
    }
```

### Property in Objective-C

```
@property(nonatomic) int x;

@synthesize x;
```

Keep in mind that the property declaration in Objective-C is splitted into two files : the `@property` goes into the header file(.h) while the `@synthesize` goes into the implementation file(.m).

To understand better how `@property` and `@synthesize` works take a look at the [apple declared properties documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html) and/or at [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10799015/use-of-property-and-synthesise) .